# Claims Management

Tags: uml, tool-uml, argouml, staruml

Im working on a project of "Claims Management" ,ive done many reseaches but i couldnt find any ideas :/i started with specifying the tools of work ( eclipse,android plugin..) now the next step is modéling a use case of claims management ( claims managament: a client hwo claims about sth wrong,he picks up the phone and call a center where an employe write down the calims and all that concern and when he saves the claims a android notification is sent to the nearest employe to go to the client house to fix the pb)
Thank u :))

Comment: So what is your question?  You seem to have started the wrong way around anyway by choosing technologies before understanding the requirements.  However, maybe they're just constraints you have.  So you now are planning to create some use case diagrams (or better perhaps user stories) to describe what the system needs to do.  That sounds sensible.  So what is the question?

Comment: My question is: have you any ideas about the use cases ? any one tried it before and had modeling it withe use cases

Comment: Since the use cases for a system should come from the users, perhaps you should be asking an insurance call centre worker's forum 'what is the process for claims management' rather than asking a software forum.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like homework. Like so many times before, I'd recommend Alistair Cockburn's standard book on use cases, ISBN 978-0201702255.

Even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case_diagram) may give you a jump start. Once you return with a first attempt of a diagram, I guess you'll find plenty of help here if you need it improved.

So you identified

> a client

and he does

> claim about sth wrong

That's good. Start with this as your main actor and use case.